# StoreKit2 - handling declined pending transactions

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit

When my app does a consumable in-app purchase, and a purchase is pending, perhaps because Ask to Buy is enabled, my app must temporarily store a large video file in the app's Documents folder. Once I receive a notification that the purchase was approved, I delete that file. But from what I've read, if the parent declines, then my app does NOT receive a notification. If that's true, then I never know when to delete that large file, outside of setting up my own expiration. Am I missing something? Isn't it a little silly that we never find out a pending transaction failed?